# Screen resolution fails with other screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a website just to test my skills with HTML, CSS, and jQuery.
However I can't fix the screen resolution on different screens.  I did all widths and heights with %, and also added a max width/height for everything (the max width/height is the same as width and height)

This is my website (it's a free domain so the link is weird)
http://mikail.comxa.com/

Comment: thanks for editing it,sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to set height to 100%. I'm not going to sit here and go through the source code, fixing every minor mistake. Just make sure your widths are set to 100%, heights you don't need to enter unless you want a max, min or set height. If you're using

`position: absolute`

ensure it's inside of a

`position: relative`

container

Comment: okay,i shall try it thanks for replying!

Comment: Also, just something I spotted. The button in the bottom right, that sends you to the top is a few pixels off and doesn't take you straight to the top.

Comment: okay but just to be clear should i change every absolute to relative?

Comment: also sorry for asking alot of questions i just started.

Comment: No. Don't set a position unless necessary. Only set an element to relative if you want a position absolute element to be contained within it. Here, look at this article on positioning:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: damn.if i put position absolute away from everything i have to reposition EVERYTHING ;( rip time.

Comment: No problem, don't be disheartened. You're obviously new to web dev and stack overflow. Don't let the harsh community put you off, you'll figure it all out eventually!

Comment: I looked at your code and you're using position absolute everywhere. The problem with using pos absolute is that it knocks the element out of the flow. This, in turn, breaks a lot of stuff and requires messy fixes.

You can insert an element without having to specify a position. By default it fits in to the flow of the content

Comment: yes,im gonna change everything.i'm gonna stop using postion untill i need it for stuff like take me to the top.i will also fix that in a min.

Comment: You got it! Here's a quick explanation without a load of tech garble that the articles put in:

Fixed: As it says on the tin, the element is fixed in one position on the screen. Good for fixed headers or "Live chat" buttons in the corner of the screen, etc.

Relative: Contains an absolute element. Placed relative to its position

Absolute: Removed from the flow of the document. Often used in responsive situations where you want an absolute element to react with the page

Comment: okay thanks,im working on postioning everything right now.last question.should i use px with height?

Comment: No, don't set the height at all, if you want it responsive. You can set a height, but it wont scale down, only the width will change. You can set the height using % or PX, it doesn't matter.

Comment: but without height everything will show up like a straight line.

Comment: You need to give the element content. The div will expand to the depth of the content.

Comment: :o never heard of it need to do some research

Comment: OK, when you create a div it has not got a height. You can place a P tag (for example) inside of the div. Without content in the P, the div not have much depth. Apply some text to the P, and the height of the div will expand to the depth of the content.

Comment: oooh now i get it! you're awesome!

Comment: Glad I could help. If you could mark my answer using the `tick` or give it an upvote, that'd be appreciated. If you need any more help, leave a comment or start a new thread. 

For advice on asking future questions with quality, and a good response, refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask it explains how to ask a good question (so you wont get downvotes like this post)

Comment: yooo!! i updated the website! 90% is fixed only thing  i got a problem with is the back to top and the 'home 'test' stuff but im sure i can fix that! u helped me out soooooo much!!! love you!!

Comment: edit;fixed everything now! ty!

Comment: Looks good! When you get a minute, just take a moment to read up on the basics of document structure and basic css. Once you get your head around it, it'll all become so much easier.